# MySQL PDO statement with IN clause?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I recently heard that soon PHP will be deprecating all of the traditional mysql functions (ex: mysql_query(), mysql_num_rows(), etc...). That being said, I'm trying to convert all of my queries into PDO format. This one particular case is giving me some difficulty,

```
$team = $_GET['team'];
$ncaa = array("Duke", "Harvard", "Yale", "Stanford");
$limit = idate('z')+14;

$list = join("','", $ncaa);

            $query = "SELECT game_id
                    FROM ncaa_current_season_games
                    WHERE game_date_int >= :game_date_int 
                    AND (home_team = :team OR away_team = :team) 
                    AND home_team IN(:list)
                    AND away_team IN(:list)
                    ORDER BY game_date_int ASC 
                    LIMIT 1";               
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute(array(':game_date_int' => $limit, ':team' => $team, ':list' => $list));

$num = $stmt->rowCount();
```

$num is returned as 0. When I had the query in my old format (not PDO), it worked just fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: My tip to debug this is get the final sql with $stmt->getQuery()->__toString();, and execute on db and look for conditions make the reverse thing becouse if you don't get any error probably the query are right, just dont satisfies your conditions. IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO, as any other raw API, is insufficient for the any real-life task.
And prepared statements are insufficient too, as they accept only *scalar data*, not whatever complex data types or arbitrary query parts.
So, a developer have to help himself with adopting a *database abstraction library*.
And use this library methods in their application code instead of raw API calls.

With raw PDO you need to create ? mark for the every IN statement value dynamically, using `str_repeat()` function or something of the kind, add every value to the data array, and then run all that train.
You can find plenty of examples on this site. Some of them are quite smart though.

But with good database access library, you can do it the way you tried (in vain) with raw PDO

```
$team = $_GET['team'];
$ncaa = array("Duke", "Harvard", "Yale", "Stanford");
$limit = idate('z')+14;

$query = "SELECT game_id
        FROM ncaa_current_season_games
        WHERE game_date_int >= ?s 
        AND (home_team = ?s OR away_team = ?s) 
        AND home_team IN(?a)
        AND away_team IN(?a)
        ORDER BY game_date_int ASC 
        LIMIT 1";               
$data = $db->getRow($query, $limit, $team, $team, $list, $list);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `:list` as one placeholder for the in clause, you need one placeholder for one value.